# Does not contain definition for RemoveBackEntry() in Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

The "RemoveBackEntry" is working in WP8 but not working in WP8.1

```
var backStackList = PageHelper.RootApplicationFrame.BackStack.ToList();

            foreach (var page in backStackList)
            {
                if (!pageName.Contains("MainPage"))
                {
                  if (page.Source.ToString().Contains(pageName))
                    {
                        PageHelper.RootApplicationFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
                    }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: first page on google has the answer to this question - did you search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one..

```
var backStackList = PageHelper.RootApplicationFrame.BackStack.ToList();

    foreach (var page in backStackList)
    {
        if (!pageName.Contains("MainPage"))
        {
          if (page.SourcePageType.ToString().Contains(pageName))
                {
                    PageHelper.RootApplicationFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(PageHelper.RootApplicationFrame.BackStack.Count - 1);
                }
         }
     }
```